# How to retrieve related records in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to find a `user`'s overdue `invoices`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def overdue_invoices
    invoices.where("overdue = ?", true)
  end
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def overdue
    balance > 0 && Date.today > due_date
  end
end
```

The problem seems to be that `overdue` is a method on the `Invoice` model, not a database column.

How can I retrieve those records anyway? And does that even make sense or would it be better to store those `true` and `false` values in the database?

Comment: What does the `Invoice#overdue` method look like?

Comment: Just added it above. `balance` is actually a database column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create an equivalent class method or [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for `overdue` on `Invoice`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.overdue
    where('balance > 0').where('? > due_date', Date.today)
  end
end
```

Then you can call `overdue` on an Invoice relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def overdue_invoices
    invoices.overdue
  end
end
```

Note that I’m assuming `due_date` is a database column, if it’s not, you cannot use this method—however, you may be able to replace it with SQL to calculate the due date from data that is in columns.

Comment: Thank, Andrew! That works really well. I have to read up on the concept of `self` now because I am not entirely sure yet why you added it to the `overdue` method.

Comment: def self.______ defines a class level method instead of a instance method.  http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ is a good writeup.